# Retrofit2 and certificate pinning

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

In my android app I want to use certificate pinning when communicating with the server.
I saw this code that uses the `keystore` that is stored in the `raw` folder.

```
OkClient client = new RetrofitClientBuilder()
.pinCertificates(getResources(), R.raw.keystore, STORE_PASS)
.build()
```

I'm using `retrofit2` and `OkHTTP3` and just saw this example:

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .certificatePinner(new CertificatePinner.Builder()
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/DmxUShsZuNiqPQsX2Oi9uv2sCnw=")
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/SXxoaOSEzPC6BgGmxAt/EAcsajw=")
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/blhOM3W9V/bVQhsWAcLYwPU6n24=")
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/T5x9IXmcrQ7YuQxXnxoCmeeQ84c=")
            .build())
    .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://api.nuuneoi.com/base/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build();
```

Does this later approach achieves the same result has the first one?

Answer (score 0):

I can say that this approach worked wonderfully for me.
Just make sure you add your endpoint correctly without the "https://" to the certificate pinner and it should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You should need to change `sha1/` to `sha256/` , it works well for me.